# Read URL content in php using For loop

Tags: php

I want to read some tricky URL

http://localhost/pizzaapp/checkOut.php?orderId[2]=3&orderId[6]=5&&orderId[10]=7&name=testName

```
foreach($_GET as $query_string_variable => $value) {
echo "$query_string_variable => $value"."<br />";
}
```

I found this way over google But it only read if this case occur (orderId=7) once in whole URL
And showing last value that is 10. But I need more than one as shown in URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. PHP will discover that orderId looks like an array.

```
foreach($_GET['orderId'] as $orderKey => $orderValue) {
    echo "$orderKey => $orderValue";
}
```

Try `var_dump($_GET)` to see how your querystring gets parsed by PHP.

Comment: Indeed it works magically. Thanks a lot. You save my day.
Also try var_dump, No it make sense.